# what is wrong with my query in oracle live sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran the following code in oracle live SQL but it gives an error. What is the problem?

```
select * from bricks full join 
((select count(*) from bricks) as "counts"
inner join (select count(*) from bricks group by colour) as "colours" 
on counts.colour=colours.colour)
on bricks.colour=bricks.colour; --a dummy condition just for connecting tables without a specific column
```

output:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are:

- `AS` before a table/sub-query alias is invalid syntax in Oracle. Remove the `AS` keywords.
- The aliases you are using are quoted identifiers which are case-sensitive and you do not use quoted identifiers with the same case when you refer to the aliases. Remove the double quotes.
- Neither the `counts` nor `colours` sub-query has a `colour` column in the `SELECT` clause and you cannot subsequently refer to non-existent columns in the `ON` clause of the join condition.

You can fix it using:

```sql
select *
from   bricks
       CROSS JOIN (select count(*) AS cnt from bricks) counts
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         select colour, count(*) AS colour_cnt
         from   bricks
         group by colour
       ) colours
       on bricks.colour=colours.colour
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bricks (id, colour) AS
SELECT 1, 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'blue' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | COLOUR | CNT | COLOUR | COLOUR_CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | red | 6 | red | 3 |
> | 2 | red | 6 | red | 3 |
> | 3 | red | 6 | red | 3 |
> | 4 | green | 6 | green | 2 |
> | 5 | green | 6 | green | 2 |
> | 6 | blue | 6 | blue | 1 |

---

However, you probably want to simplify things and use the analytic `COUNT() OVER (...)` function and eliminate the self-joins:

```sql
select b.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY colour) AS colour_cnt
from   bricks b;
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | COLOUR | CNT | COLOUR_CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 6 | blue | 6 | 1 |
> | 5 | green | 6 | 2 |
> | 4 | green | 6 | 2 |
> | 2 | red | 6 | 3 |
> | 1 | red | 6 | 3 |
> | 3 | red | 6 | 3 |

(identical other than not duplicating the colours column)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9ccfd8800066fb8f01875ef326ea8573)*

Comment: @aforz Did you try the edit I made a few minutes before your comment (which works in db<>fiddle)? Or the original version, which I fixed. Also, do not use the top query; use the bottom query with the analytic functions.

Comment: I got it, but really why should columns be selected?

Comment: yes thanks that was for before

Comment: @aforz You use `on counts.colour=colours.colour` in the join condition but neither `select count(*) from bricks` nor `select count(*) from bricks group by colour` has a `colour` column in the `SELECT` clause of the query so `counts.colour` and `colours.colour` both refer to columns that do not exist.